# Flask validation not logging me in

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I am trying to create a very basic login form with flask, with sqlite storing the username and password. Before you say it, i am aware i have not hashed passwords etc, this is just me practicing the very basics.
I have a username and password stored in the database and for some reason no matter what I try I cannot seem to log in, almost as if my code is not querying the database correctly or something

I have tried changing the code and printing info and it doesn't seem to be connecting to the database correctly.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect
from calendar_formulas import get_month, get_year, generate_calendar
from datetime import datetime
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import UserMixin, login_user, LoginManager, login_required, logout_user, current_user
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Length, ValidationError
import pytest

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///instance, database.db'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'thisisasecretkey'
db = SQLAlchemy()
db.init_app(app)



class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"User(id={self.id}, username='{self.username}')"



login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = "log_in"

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(user_id)

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField(validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=20)],
                           render_kw={"placeholder": "Username"})
    password = PasswordField(validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=20)],
                             render_kw={"placeholder": "Password"})
    submit = SubmitField("Login")



@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def log_in():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user and user.check_password(form.password.data):
            login_user(user)
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('log_in.html', form=form)


@app.route("/home", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def home():
    years = get_year()
    months = get_month()

    selected_year = int(request.args.get('year', datetime.now().year))
    selected_month = int(request.args.get('month', datetime.now().month))

    calendar_data = generate_calendar(selected_year, selected_month)

    return render_template('home.html', years=years,
                           months=months, selected_year=selected_year,
                           selected_month=selected_month,
                           calendar_data=calendar_data)



    



if __name__ == "__main__":
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

[flask_sqlalchemy.config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/config/#flask_sqlalchemy.config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)

> flask_sqlalchemy.config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
> The database connection URI used for the default engine. It can be either a string or a SQLAlchemy URL instance

Change

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///instance, database.db'
```

into

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
```

Also you didn't added `check_password` method with `User` model

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    
    ... Rest of your codes

    def check_password(self, password):
        # add your validation here
        return False
```

Also see more about [SQLAlchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/quickstart/#installation)